# Render <div> outside of <table>

Tags: html, css

I have a table `<td>` which contains an `<input>` control. Typing text in the input shows a `<div>` with search results. Specifically, if you start typing owner's name, people whose name contains that text will list in the search results. Here it is in action:

- Before typing:
  [image: Document owner column input waiting for text]
- After typing 'b' in the document owner input:
  [image: Search result div is shown for input "b"]

The problem is that the `<div>` with the search results is showing inside the table, but I want it to overflow.

Here is the related HTML code:

```
<table class="table">
   ...
   <tr>
      ...
      <td>
         <div class="people-picker">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type user name">
         </div>
         <div class="search-results-wrapper">
            <div class="search-results">
               ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </td>
      ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the CSS for the related classes:

```
.table {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-spacing: 0;
   overflow-x: auto;
}

.table td {
   padding: 8px 12px;
   vertical-align: top;
   user-select: none;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.people-picker {
   min-width: 148px;
}

.people-picker input {
   width: 100%;
   background: url('../img/users-black.svg') no-repeat scroll right center;
   padding-right: 32px;
}

.search-results-wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

.search-results {
   position: absolute;
   top: 4px;
   z-index: 2000;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

How do I make the `.search-results <div>` render under the `.people-picker <div>` but outside of the table? Thanks, I appreciate your help!

Comment: When  you say 'outside of the table' do you mean 'on top of the table' - that is flowing beneath people picker but appearing on top of the cells below?

Comment: @AHaworth Correct, I want it to be on top of the table and cells below, if any.

Comment: The css of the table and td is not shown. Try this `.people-picker { min-width: 148px; max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;  }`

Comment: I just added the CSS for the `<table>` and `<td>`. I tried your suggestion for `.people-picker` class, but still getting the same result.

Comment: put the div outside of the table. handle the logic via JS for showing / hiding the people-picker. look up other autocompletes on how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an overlay to show the results. From your example:

CSS

```
.search-results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: 2000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="search-results-wrapper">
    <div id="overlay" class="search-results">
```

and in JS show or hide the results:

```
let isHidden = true;

function showHide() {
  if (isHidden) {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
  } else {   
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
  }
  isHidden = !isHidden;
}
```

Check this StackBlitz example based on your code: https://web-platform-fifydh.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Here check out this answer. I did it using only css and html and but as mentioned in the question that you wanted to render div outside of table, this does work.

Hope this helps!

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
table,
tr,
td {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.table td {
  background: red;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#searchUser {
  min-width: 148px;
}

.search-results-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: -105px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transitions: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.search-results {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: inherit;
  max-height: fit-content;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: 2000;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .search-results-wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="searchUser" placeholder="Type user name">
      <div class="search-results-wrapper">
        <div class="search-results">
          <p>Demo text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```